# 404 Not Found Error for PHPmyAdmin on DigitalOcean droplet following linking of existing domain name

Tags: mysql, spring, apache, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-access-a-java-web-application-by-a-domain-name-using-tomcat-8

After following all the steps and the related guides linked to in the post above, I was able to access my Java Spring application using "mywebsite.com:8080/appname".

Unfortunately, unlike before, I am unable to reach my phpmyadmin installation using either "mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin" or "droplet-ip/phpmyadmin" (which worked fine previously) and instead I get a 404 error saying phpmyadmin directory does not exist.

Additionally, even after following all the tips in said post I'm also unable to reach my app using just "mywebsite.com" and still have to add the additional ":8080/appname", contrary to what the post suggests.

I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` and have been sure to select apache2 during the installation, but still have no success. I can still access my TomCat manager, and the apache home page when using "mywebsite.com" or "droplet-ip".

If any further information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: This answer helped me for solving the issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 15.04 and 16.04

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```